# Fetching Record From CoreData according to user auth

Tags: swift, core-data, swift4

User can save items to cart and then he can view the cart and see his saved items, but the problem that when I fetched record data from CoreData I am getting all users saved items. I wrote condition to fix that issue, but I am getting nil error. Can someone explain why this happen and how to solve it?

Explaining the problem, for exampe I am having user A and user B when user A saved some items to cart, user B will get those items in his cart as well

```
 func fetchRecordFromDatabase(){
        let userID = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid

        let context = objAppDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
        let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>.init(entityName: "Cart")

        do{
        result = try context.fetch(fetchRequest) as! [NSManagedObject]
            for data in result{
                if data == data{
                let obj = userNSObj()
                obj.itemName = data.value(forKey: "itemName") as! String
                obj.uid = data.value(forKey: "uid") as! String

                    if userID == obj.uid{
                        self.arrayAddress.append(obj)
                                  }
                         }else{
                            print("alert")
                        }}

                 }catch{
                      print("Failed")
                 }

             }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to add an appropriate predicate to fetch only the records with the given UID.

```
func fetchRecordFromDatabase(){
    guard let userID = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else { print("Invalid user ID"); return }

    let context = objAppDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<Cart>(entityName: "Cart")
    fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "uid == %@", userID)

    do {
        let carts = try context.fetch(fetchRequest)
        for cart in carts {
            let obj = userNSObj()
            obj.itemName = cart.itemName
            obj.uid = cart.uid
            self.arrayAddress.append(obj)
        }
    } catch {
        print(error)
    }
}
```

Note:

I have no idea what `userNSObj` does. If you specify the generic type of the `FetchRequest` (as already suggested in one of your previous questions) you get `Cart` items without any type cast. And it's highly recommended to use type safe dot notation `data.uid` rather than unreliable KVC `data.value(forKey: "uid") as! String`.